# Yesod in-place editing widget

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm interesting in creating a widget in Yesod with the following properties:

- By default, it renders simply as some text "Title"
- When moused-over, a small link "Edit this" appears on the upper-right corner
- If the user clicks on the link or mouses over it, the text is replaced with a text field/area with the text in it, for editing
- When the user presses ENTER, a REST request is made to the server to update the value; when the update is confirmed the form disappears and updated text is now present in the document

To a large degree, this is a strictly JS job which is mostly out of scope for Yesod.  However, there is one important point: we'd like the form itself should be generated by Yesod using yesod-forms, and not wired up manually. But the situation here is a bit strange: normally forms are static, but here the form needs to be different depending on what the data is, and Yesod might need to ship a new form to the user after the REST update. Can Yesod do this? Additionally, what is the story, as far as validation is concerned?

Comment: You need to make an AJAX handler. This handler could use the `yesod-forms` package by rendering the form to JSON and parsing a JSON result as the form result, but that adapter does afaik still have to be written. It'd probably be easier to just make a specialized AJAX adapter.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just grab the HTML of the form via AJAX?

Comment: The main difficulty is an ordinary form will cause a full page update, and you'd only want that element to update, right?

Comment: Hmm, it also looks like there doesn't presently exist an adapter for converting forms into JSON data.  I suppose the most important thing is supplying the CSRF token...

Comment: @EdwardZ.Yang did you ever solve this? You should post the answer. (Sorry, being an unanswered-questions pest today :-) )

Comment: No, I ended up doing the stupid thing.

Comment: I'm in that same situation, and I basically need the exact same thing (modulo a few trivial modifications.) My current state of knowledge is that one cannot use yesod's forms for this type of thing, and needs to just do everything manually client-side, then ship JSON objects to the server (the latter part is easy, it's just disappointing that Yesod can't help any of the client-side things, and you give up the validation an XSS protection of Yesod's forms.)

Comment: I find myself in the same situation. Is there a better answer two and a half years later?